# Multiple issues during Sylius installation

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

im trying to install Sylius with composer for an e commerce project however i just cant get it done..i follow the docs but i always get an other error when i fix one. 
already fixed some errors eg. incl extension exception, paypal bundle renaming issues on git and memory size problem.

Now where im stuck:
When i fill the parameters with the interactive script

- if i give any password for the database i get this:
  Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException
  Acces denied for user 'root'@localhost
- if i dont give password then i get this:
  Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException
  SQLSTATE[HY000]Unknown database databasename_dev (it appends _dev prefix)

then in both cases it ends up with this:  RunTimeException
An error occured when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command

and the proccess is terminated with this exception..

i tried if i could continue with the $ cd acme
$ php app/console sylius:install commands but:

- if i gave a password then get acces denied Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException
- if didnt then Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException
  SQLSTATE[HY000]Unknown database databasename_dev

i created the database manually which seems to solve the problem however get this: General error: 1007 cant create database databasename_dev; database exists
(i dont think this solution is the right one)

but after this it doesnt terminate yet and creates the database schema and then after some installation it terminates with this: 
RuntimeException 
The source file "C:\Users\user\acme\app/../web/bundles/cmfcreate/vendor/create/themes/midgard-tags/tags.css" does not exists

i checked the page if it may useable but got twig exception that currency not found and many components are missing from the page..

Answer (score 0):

What's your workspace?

If you work on Windows with WAMP I'll give you some things to check :

- set the database port to : **3306**
- **create a new user** for the database, juste for your sylius project
- when you run create-project commande, in databaseport write : **localhost**

I hope it helps you.